# How to run only rake task once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rake-task

I am using Ruby on Rails and Heroku.

I would like something like rake db:migrate, where it will only run the parts that have not been run before.

I can set a rake task that can run other rake task, but is there in way to only run those that did not run before?

What are any alternative, if I want rake tasks to be run automatically?

Comment: `rake db:migrate` checks a database table that stores the timestamp of the last migration run. You'd probably have to implement something like that.

Comment: Yea I need something that like a db:migrate, but my rake tasks are not limited to database alone, so I cant just check the database for the relation

Comment: no, I mean rails makes a special database table to store this information and checks it when it runs that rake task. I'm suggesting you create a table for this purpose and store the tasks you have run there.

Answer (score 0):

first of, running a rake task twice, ie `rake db:migrate` will neither duplicate nor overwrite your database columns if they already exist.

For example capistrano, used to deploy your rails app to basically anywhere, will rerun tasks like `db:migrate`or `assets:precompile` every time you deploy your app. So no need to worry about that really.

To run tasks automatically you will need something like a cron job. [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) is a great ruby gem that allows you to install a job like this with the beloved ruby syntax.

After installing the gem and running `wheneverize .` in the root of your rails app, you may edit the scheduler.rb and add something like:

```
every :sunday, :at => '12pm' do
    rake my:awesome:task
end
```

The Github page as well as the default `scheduler.rb` hold many useful examples of how these jobs are built.

with `whenever --update-crontab` you can write your rubyesque cronjobs into the crontab, which will run your tasks periodically at the time you want them to.

** edit

multiple tasks in one:

```
task :setup => [:a, :b, :c]
task :a do 
     %x(bash command)
end
task :b do 
     rake db:migrate
end
task :c do 
     rake whatever
end
```

Comment: I am planning to run a scheduler, but my problem is, how can that scheduler know only to run task 'b' and task 'c', because it ran task 'a' the previous time.

Comment: The scheduler itself is not very smart. So you might not be able to achieve this, unless you use some nasty condittion. You should know which task should be run or not. By creating multiple jobs, you have complete control over which task is running at what time

Comment: The ultimate goal is to delegate the push to a release team, and they dont need to know anything about rake tasks or new tables being created. I need them to just click a script and that is it.

Comment: That does not make a lot of sense to me. So you either need a deployment tool, that runs these tasks for you under the hood with a simple command (ie. capistrano `cap production deploy` - that's it).
If you just want to run multiple tasks using only one of them, check my edit.